# How to Free a Port in .NET....after a TCPListener has recieved a required thing from remote client

Tags: .net, port, tcplistener

How to Free a Port in .NET used by TCPListener....
after a TCPListener has recieved a required thing from

Answer (score 2):

Just call the Stop-method on the TcpListener.

Answer (score 0):

We first established the first Socket:

```
     Socket socket1; 
     IPEndPoint localEP = new IPEndPoint (IPAddress.Any, 20000); 
     Socket1 = new Socket (AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp); 
     Socket1.Bind (localEP);
```

Then a second Socket:

```
     Socket socket2 
     IPEndPoint localEP = new IPEndPoint (IPAddress.Any, 20000); 
     Socket2 = new Socket (AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp); 
     Socket2.SetSocketOption (SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.ReuseAddress, true); 
    / / Please note this one. True ReuseAddress options will be set to allow the socket to bind already in use in the address. 
     Socket2.Bind (localEP);
```

This will be bundled Socket1 and Socket2 in the same port on the.